# How to determine the length of a section of a base of a cone?

Tags: geometry

Say I have a cone where I have 3D slice of it running from the apex to the base. The edges of the slice meet at the apex at a $150°$ angle. We are assuming that we know the lengths of the slice's edges and that lengths of both of these edges are equal. Given these details, how would I be able to find the length of the section of the cone's base that is part of the slice?

Here is an image to sorta show what I am referring to. The edges of the slice are shown by the two dark gray lines. The segment of the edge of the cone's base that is in between the dark gray lines is what I am trying to find. The $150°$ angle is located at the apex of the cone, in between the lines. NOTE: image is not to scale.

[image: cone]

Comment: Figure required.

Comment: @ A Child of God You have given cone vertical angle only and no length in the section as a linear dimension like slant height, center hight. So it is impossible to say. If height $h$ is known,  then the diameter you seek Is $ 2 h \tan 75^{\circ} $

Comment: @YvesDaoust I added a figure

Comment: There is not enough information to answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am not asking for an answer but an equation so I can solve the answer myself depending on the height of the cone or the length between the apex and base of the cone

Comment: @AChildofGod: maybe you should care to look at the answers. My -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that the base of the cone is a unit circle and the height is $h$. The requested angle (equal to the arc length) is denoted $\theta$, while the given angle between the apothems is $\phi$.

Let the apex of the cone be at $(0,0,h)$, and the feet of the apothems $(1,0,0)$ and $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0)$. We express the angle $\phi$ by the dot product of two unit vectord

$$\cos\phi=\frac{(-1,0,h)}{\sqrt{1+h^2}}\cdot\frac{(-\cos\theta,-\sin\theta,h)}{\sqrt{1+h^2}}.$$

Hence

$$\cos\theta=(1+h^2)\cos\phi-h^2.$$

Comment: And this gives us the length of the base's edge between the lines?

Comment: @AChildofGod: yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

Indicating with $a$ the lenght of the edges, the base $B$ is given by

$$\sin 75°=\frac{\frac{B}2}{a}=\frac{B}{2a}\implies B=2a\cdot \sin 75°$$

We have used the relationship for right triangle indicated in the following figure with

- $\theta=\frac{150°}{2}=75°$
- hypotenuse$\,=a$
- opposite $=$ half base

[image]

Comment: Could possible explain why this is true?

Comment: @AChildofGod It is a property for right triangle, I've added sketch, we have $\theta=150°/2=75°$ and hypotenuse is $a$

Comment: When I said a slice, I did not mean a cross section. Say someone were to cut a cone at two places, forming somewhat of triangular prism, but with a curved edge and face like one would expect from being cut from a cone

Comment: I added a figure in my question to hopefully help explain what I wanting